# Looking to make a retractable disco ball

Tags: electrical-engineering, structures

I am looking to make a disco ball that sits in its normal position, attached to a ceiling, but to be able to hit a switch and it track upwards at a 90° angle to be hidden horizontally in a case. I am looking to attach this box to the rafters of a porch outside.

I want to have the ball attached to a mechanism that lifts the ball from a traditional vertical position to 90° horizontally upwards.

Comment: sounds like an electric winch.

Comment: I don't think "tracts" means what you think it means. (Check the dictionary.) It's not a verb so it is not clear what you are describing.

Comment: I see your edit but you haven't asked a question. See the [Tour] to learn how SE sites work and how to ask a good question that's on-topic for the site.

Comment: the description is clear only in your head ... please draw a diagram for the rest of us